What's the meaning of 'spoosh'?
I can't find the word 'spoosh' in the lexicon? Does it really exist? What's the meaning of it?

and I like to sort of spoosh it about.




What was the source of that first image?

@alphabet https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrcCbdWwCBc&t=139s     4:17

That speaker either is Canadian or has some sort of odd regional US accent, in case this is some sort of regionalism. But my best guess is that this is just a variant of smoosh.

@alphabet still none the wiser with smoosh.

I can only find a suggested definition in UD. And it's not one to use for 'splash [something] about with abandon'. 'Sploosh' works better, and is in mainstream dictionaries.

If it's not in a dictionary then it's not a mainstream word.

So this is a word the OP came across in a YouTube video, in subtitles, or on-screen text? Isn't it most likely a typo or subtitle error or something of the sort?
